# How do I get friends Faceook ID from App Request deep link using FB.GetAppLink in Unity?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5.4 with the latest Facebook API (7.8) for this.

I am trying to find out what my friends Facebook ID is after clicking a Game Request they sent me. I have looked into and have been using FB.GetAppLink but it doesnt appear to give me the friends Facebook ID, only my Facebook ID and the games ID.

I am needing this information so that after accepting their challenge I can send them back a gift if I was successful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after umping through a lot of hoops...

```
public void GetDeepLink ()
{
    FB.GetAppLink(DeepLinkCallBack);
}

public void DeepLinkCallBack(IAppLinkResult result)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dict = result.ResultDictionary;

        if (dict.ContainsKey("target_url"))
        {
            string url = dict["target_url"].ToString();
            string keyword = "request_ids=";
            int k = 0;
            while (k < url.Length - keyword.Length && !url.Substring(k, keyword.Length).Equals(keyword))
                k++;
            k += keyword.Length;
            int l = k;
            while (url[l] != '&' && url[l] != '%')
                l++;
            string id = url.Substring(k, l - k);

            FB.API("/" + id + "_" + AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId, HttpMethod.GET, DeepLinkCallBackCallBack);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Applink Error :" + result.Error);
        }
    }
}

void DeepLinkCallBackCallBack(IGraphResult result)
{
    Debug.Log("Request callback");
    Debug.Log("========================");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dict = result.ResultDictionary;

        if (dict.ContainsKey("from"))
        {
            IDictionary<string,object> from = dict["from"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
            if (from.ContainsKey("name"))
            {
                Debug.Log(from["name"]);
                deepLinkUserName = from["name"].ToString();
            }
            if (from.ContainsKey("id"))
            {
                deepLinkUserName = from["name"].ToString();
                FB.API("/" + dict["id"], HttpMethod.DELETE, null);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error in request:" + result.Error);
    }
}
```